# Model em sessões

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, session

Tenho uma GRID (tabela) que ao selecionar um item através da ID eu carrego a entidade em uma sessão via ajax.

```
public static class Sessoes
    {
        public static Produto Produto
        {
            get
            {
                return (Produto)HttpContext.Current.Session["Produto"];
            }
            set
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["Produto"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Me pergunto se seria uma decisão ruim salvar toda entidade em uma sessão? O que vocês acham? Existe/conhecem alguma desvantagem no uso dessa **prática**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem várias desvantagens.

[Neste link, por exemplo, o autor ensina como capturar facilmente dados de uma sessão](http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/01/aspnet-session-hijacking-with-google.html).

Ao colocar seu `Produto` dentro de uma `Session`, você perde a capacidade de carga preguiçosa, porque a atribuição fará o objeto ser destacado do contexto. Alterações nele também não serão mapeadas.

Há ainda o agravante de você usar sua aplicação em um ambiente distribuído, com balanceamento de carga (ambientes Azure, que não sejam máquinas virtuais, por exemplo). Usando essa abordagem, seu aplicativo irá falhar em tempo de execução, pois `Sessions` não foram bem implementadas para este tipo de ambiente.

A `Session` precisa ser vista como uma cache temporária por usuário, e não como um recurso de armazenamento geral de dados, como é, por exemplo, uma `ViewBag` ou um dicionário `ViewData`.

Comment: Aqui na empresa onde trabalho está rolando uma discussão sobre isso... Na minha opinião deveríamos salvar a ID e pegar a entidade pela ID, por conta de uma linha de código pra retornar a entidade está dando um fuzue! Em breva aceito a resposta, vamos ver se mais alguém posta algo!

Comment: @Trxplz0 Correto. Pela Id, não há problemas. O importante é não manter tantos dados em um objeto temporário e volátil como a `Session`.

Comment: Cigano, sobre a parte "Sessions não fora bem... ambiente", você quer dizer in-process né? Pois, se não me engano, o Asp.NET State Service é exatamente pra isso não é?

Comment: @Trxplz0 Não sei. Nunca usei este recurso. Aliás, seria até uma boa eu dar uma olhada nisso.

Comment: De qualquer maneira, não é bom salvar uma entidade na Session!

Comment: @Trxplz0 Exatamente.